# Azure Import/Export tool dataset.csv and multiple session folders

Tags: azure

I am in the process of copying a large set of data to an Azure Blob Storage area.  My source set of data has a large number of files that I do not want to move, so my first thought was to create a DataSet.csv file of just the files I *do* want to copy.  As a test, I created a csv file where each row is a single file that I want to include.

> BasePath,DstBlobPathOrPrefix,BlobType,Disposition,MetadataFile,PropertiesFile
>   "\\SERVER\Share\Folder1\Item1\Page1\full.jpg","containername/Src/Folder1/Item1/Page1/full.jpg",BlockBlob,overwrite,"None",None
>   "\\SERVER\Share\Folder1\Item1\Page1\thumb.jpg","containername/Src/Folder1/Item1/Page1/thumb.jpg",BlockBlob,overwrite,"None",None
>   etc.

When I run the Import/Export tool (WAImportExport.exe) it seems to create a single folder on the destination for each file, so that it ends up looking like:
session#1
-session#1-0
-session#1-1
-session#1-2
etc.

All files share the same base, but do output their filename in the CSV.  Is there any way to avoid this, so that all the files go into a single "session#1" folder?  If possible, I'd like to avoid creating N-thousand folders on the destination drive.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should worry about the way the files are stored on the disk, as they will be converted back to the directory structure you specified in the .csv file.

Here's what the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-import-export-tool-preparing-hard-drives-import) says:

> **How does the WAImportExport tool work on multiple source dir and disks?**
>
> If the data size is greater than the disk size, the WAImportExport
>   tool will distribute the data across the disks in an optimized way.
>   The data copy to multiple disks can be done in parallel or
>   sequentially. There is no limit on the number of disks the data can be
>   written to simultaneously. The tool will distribute data based on disk
>   size and folder size. It will select the disk that is most optimized
>   for the object-size. **The data when uploaded to the storage account
>   will be converged back to the specified directory structure.**